# Parse.com data import with objectId preserved

Tags: parse-platform

Is there a way to import data, preferably Json into Parse database with preserving objectIds and existing relationships? 
I found many old post that mention you can only preserve objectId if I use the data browser button from the UI tools, however I would like to do this programmatically in order to automate this task.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do that. You would just get your existing object IDs and create new objects using the same IDs and save them on your new table/parse project.